# Express & React on ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, express

I am  a web developer and I am making Express & React web app.

[project structure...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpJKw.png)

package.json file for express like this.

```
{
  "name": "reactcurd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm run build && cd build && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "sync-mysql": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

and package.json file for react (client directory) like this.

```
{
  "name": "reactcrud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://myserver.com:5000/",
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

this works on win10 using "yarn dev " command... but does not work on ubuntu.
ports are opened (3000 & 5000 port)

please Help me...
Thank you....

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please define "does not work".

Comment: Is there is any error you are getting that can help us see the problem ?